# Is the "MOV" instruction in Assembly to allocate memory?

Tags: assembly

I notice that MOV is supposed to copy and overwrite data to and from registers, but if there's no present data in any other register, does MOV move a certain sized byte(s) from RAM to the register to temporarily hold it, or how does this work exactly?

To clarify my question, say I use:

```
MOV AL, 0x10;
```

In such a case, where is the "10" digit data that is moved to the 8-bit register?

Is this moved from RAM to AL as eight bits to hold, or is the "10" byte just a scratchpad number that is not in memory?

I don't understand this, and it would be amazing if someone could straighten this out.

My problem is that I need to know where and how much memory is used, and how and what exactly is addressing it(and tutorials don't make clear of this).

Comment: It's in the instruction itself.

Comment: @GManNickG  Could you clarify that a little more? So you're saying that the RAM is accessed by the instruction itself, and not moved? I don't get it.

Comment: can you tell us why you need to know this. please give more context

Comment: Perhaps the missing concept is that MOV isn't a single instruction. There are tons of them, one moves 10 to AL, another moves 42 to BX, etc.

Comment: You don't really "allocate" memory in ASM in the traditional sense. The memory is all there.

Answer (score 6):

Guessing at the mental block: it is important to understand that RAM both contains code *and* data.  The value 0x10 comes from code.  It was encoded into the machine code instruction by the assembler.  That code got loaded into RAM by the operating system when it started executing your code.

Notable is that it is not a variable, the instruction will *always* load 0x10, regardless of the state of your program.  Other parts of RAM store the data that you declared in your assembly program.  Like the .data and .stack sections.  But is not otherwise used by this particular instruction.

Adding to the possible confusion:  it doesn't *have* to be in RAM.  On embedded systems without an operating system or boot drive, the code is often burned into ROM instead.  The processor doesn't otherwise care about it, it just reads bytes from a memory bus, using the EIP register (the instruction pointer) to tell the memory sub-system what bytes it needs.

Answer (score 4):

your code lives in RAM ie, the bytes that represent `MOV AL, 0x10;`,  the 0x10 is part of the instruction, its not stored seperately.  Typically it wont be coming from RAM at the point of execution but a instruction pipeline on the CPU,  The CPU fetches instructions from RAM into its pipelines as it see's fit.

for a great free online book on assembly try http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/artofasm.html

chapter 4 deals with memory addressing  http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH04/CH04-1.html

there are a lot of concepts to get your head around, memory addressing in all its forms and how to work with the CPU architecture can seem daunting at first, but will slowly start making sense as you try stuff out.

Comment: I still really don't understand how that makes sense ... the instruction is stored in RAM, but how do you move the data to the processor to work with it? And when it's "in" the processor, how do you know when and what is concurrently in RAM, or moved between the devices interchangeably between instructions in parallel?

Comment: well, for instructions like the one you have shown, it doesn't involve accessing RAM for data purposes,  the instruction contains all the necessary parts.   For addressing memory so that you can store data or retrieve data, generally you have an allocated chunk of memory ( how you get that depends on whether this is running on an OS, or is embedded, or something else).  You load an addressing register with the start of that chunk, and then use a mov with an index, like mov     al, [eax][ebx]

Comment: where eax would hold the base memory address of the chunk,  and ebx would hold an index into that chunk where you want to access the data

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the primary memory in your device/machine is RAM. So basically your application would be exists there at run-time (after you run that application from hard disk for example, it will be load into the device memory). By the way, all of the binary-instructions which are executable for the processor are in RAM now.

To simplify that, let say processor will start reading the memory from the very first cells, like 0, will try to understand what to do with that, and after finishing will move on to the next one which is 1 in this case and so on.

Now let say `mov al, 0x10` is equal to `0xAABB` in our imaginary processor. At the physical memory, `0xAA` is stored at the cell number `20` and `0xBB` at `21`. Our processor is still busy to reading the stream. When it reaches the memory at `20`, it would load the binary value that is `0xAA` in this case. By the way, in our processor's documentation it means **Fill up the AL with the Following data**. The Following data in our case is `0xBB`, so the processor will do that.

As you can see:

- here, in our example, everything exists in the RAM (at run-time) including executable instructions, data, etc.
- CPU reads it from RAM and will try to do whatever is supposed/necessary to do by that
- As you may noticed that `mov al, 0x10` wasn't allocate at the **run-time**, but it was all hard-coded by the compiler, and stored into an executable file (for example)
- So, that imaginary `0xBB` is exists on the RAM, but you can't change it at the run-time. Again keep it in mind that it wasn't also created at the run-time, it was just loaded into the RAM, at run-time

I hope it helps you understand that better.

Answer (score 1):

assembly instruction

```
mov al, 0x10
```

is equal to `0xb010` in binary

```
mov al, 0xff
```

is equal to 0xb0ff

if you are on windows
you can click start - run - debug
and in a debug window, write

```
a      
[Enter]
mov al, ff
[Enter]
[Enter]
```

it change 
mov al, ff 
to binary

and then you can see 0xb0ff
by..

```
u 100
[Enter]

a 
mov al, ff
```

means 'assemble' mov al, ff and save to current location(may be 0x100)

`u 100` means 'unassemble' location 0x100

Comment: the file contains 0xb0ff and loaded on ram when you execute it. and cpu read ram and execute 0xb0ff.